# How do I view a webcam image on OS X 10.11

Tags: macos, webcam

How do I view a webcam image on OS X 10.11. I have a webcam previously used on Windows and just want to use it as a camera.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you just want to see what your webcam is showing:

`Open QuickTime Player --> File --> New Movie Recording`

It will give the option to record what your webcam is seeing but you don't have to. It will show a video feed from your webcam.

As an alternative to QuickTime Player you can use VLC.  You'll have to download it from [VLC's website](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html).

Once installed:

`Open VLC --> File --> Open Capture Device --> Tick Video --> Choose your camera for the drop down list --> Click Open`